# Laravel relationship with method "with" returns null

Tags: laravel, null, relationship

Today I wanted to do some clean code so just started selecting columns for with relationship. With this code:

```
\App\Genre::with([
   'family'
      ])->where([
         'slug' => $slug,
         'is_active' => true
      ])->first();
```

everything is working fine. But when I start selecting columns for "with" method:

```
\App\Genre::with([
   'family' => function ($query) {
       $query->select('name_pl', 'name_lat');
    }])->where([
       'slug' => $slug,
       'is_active' => true
    ])->first();
```

I got that family is null (but it should be an object with columns: name_pl, name_lat). What I am doing wrong?

family method in Genre class looks like this:

```
public function family () {
    return $this->belongsTo(Family::class);
}
```

I am using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try:

```php
\App\Genre::with('family:name_pl,name_lat')->where([
    'slug' => $slug,
    'is_active' => true
])->first();
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about that. It's working pretty well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need to add a related column to the list of selected columns, otherwise Laravel won't b able to match the data to eager-load.

Assuming that `Genre` has a `family_id` and `Family` has an `id` primary key column specified, you need this:

```
$query->select('id', 'name_pl', 'name_lat'); // See the id added here?
```

Should do the trick.

For clarity, the matching I mentioned is this one:

```
select * from genre

select * from family where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

-- where the comma-separated list of IDs consists of the unique `family_id` values retrieved in the first query.

Comment: Yes, you have right but I still prefer Hazem Emad's solutions. It looks kinda smarter.